# SQL sort database after delete a row data

Tags: php, sql

I looked through numerous examples but I am still having some issues.
I want to be able to sort SQL table after a row is deleted.

What I wanted to do:

```
sid type 
1   1
1   2
1   3
2   1
2   2
3   1
3   2
3   3
3   4
4   1
4   2
```

Let's say I deleted type 2 - sid 3, it'll be sorted from

```
sid type 
1   1
1   2
1   3
2   1
2   2
3   1

3   3
3   4
4   1
4   2
```

to

```
sid type 
1   1
1   2
1   3
2   1
2   2
3   1

3   2
3   3
4   1
4   2
```

My SQL structure:

```
$deleteData = $con->prepare("DELETE FROM target WHERE sid=? AND type=?");
$deleteData->bind_param("ii", $sid, $type); 

$sid= $_POST['sid'];
$type= $_POST['type'];

$deleteData -> execute(); 

$updateData = $con->prepare("UPDATE 
`                               target
                            SET 
                                type = type - 1 
                            WHERE 
                                sid = $sid AND type > $type");
$updateData -> execute();
```

Honestly, I'm not sure what I'm doing on the updateData part. How do I set it so that it'll be reordered?

Comment: You query looks ok, do you have any error or not getting the right result?

Comment: You code looks like it should do what you intend it to do.

Comment: Given your example, that's not sorting, that's altering the data. What you'd probably need to do is query each distinct SID and update the "Type" to be in a sequence. I'd be curious to know precisely *why* you'd like to do this though? Maybe you just actually want a calculated field instead... Your underlying data shouldn't need re-identifying just because one record has been deleted.

Comment: why you use binding parameter for first query but not for second?

Comment: second binding is broken. I am just typing that in because I have no clue how it suppose to run. The second query actually doesn't work. Also tried binding the thing.

Comment: @JeffWatkins Could you give an example on how I am suppose to update it correctly? I am having issues doing it =[

Comment: What is your real-world use-case?

Comment: In your code there is also an extra `\` `

Comment: Don't try to renumber your data!!! Foreign keys will break, you'll have inconsistent data etc.

Comment: @JeffWatkins I edited the post with my actual code. I should've started with that

Comment: So your table have `user_id`?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Yes. user_id isn't actually linked or associated with any reference.

Comment: I mean there is in your sample data now.

Comment: yes. Its in the data table.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I re-read your comment.. and that was the issue with the extra `. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second query doesnt work is because you dont have the parameter binding correct.

You should have

```
$updateData = $con->prepare("UPDATE 
                               target
                            SET 
                                type = type - 1 
                            WHERE 
                                sid = > ? AND type > ?");
$updateData->bind_param("ii", $sid, $type);
```

In db your query works ok as you can see in the fiddle.

**[Sql Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/36101/1)**

```
CREATE TABLE target
    (`sid` int, `type` int)
;

INSERT INTO target
    (`sid`, `type`)
VALUES
    (1, 1),
    (1, 2),
    (1, 3),
    (2, 1),
    (2, 2),
    (3, 1),
    (3, 2),
    (3, 3),
    (3, 4),
    (4, 1),
    (4, 2)
;

DELETE FROM target WHERE sid=3 AND type=2;

UPDATE  target
SET 
    type = type - 1 
WHERE 
    sid = 3 AND type > 2 ;


SELECT *
FROM target;
```